# Circular dependency in DI detected for ApplicationRef. How to fix it

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, angular10

I am a beginner in Angular and tried to implement global error handling in the application for this purpose I create appErrorHandler class and implement ErrorHandler and I inject Toast Service on this class but it shows me above error.
AppErrorHandler class.

```
  @Injectable()
 export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

constructor(private toastService: ToastrService) {}

handleError(error: any): void {
    this.toastService.error("An unexpected error","Error");
}
```

}

AppModule

```
 providers: [
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler },
MakeService
],
 imports: [
BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ToastrModule.forRoot(
  {
    timeOut: 6000,
   positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
   preventDuplicates: true,
  }
),
RouterModule.forRoot([
  
  {  path:'', component:HomeComponent },
  {  path:'vehicle-form', component:VehicleFormComponent },
  
]),
```

],

[image: Error image]

Comment: aren't you missing `{providedIn: 'root'}` in the `AppErrorHandler`'s `@Injectable` decorator?

Comment: it does not make a difference

Comment: I see... is there any chance you could replicate the thing in stackblitz? that would really be helpful :)

Comment: To handle this scenario, you can make use of 2 approaches

 - Make use of [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) eg: [Example-HttpInterceptor](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-angular-interceptors-to-manage-http-requests-and-error-handling)

 - Creating Factor Method eg: [Resolve-Circular-Dependency](https://www.codelord.net/2016/11/10/circular-dependencies-in-angular-and-the-injector-service/)

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue, and didn't find the real cause. Anyway, this can be fixed by hack (source: https://github.com/ngneat/hot-toast/issues/70)

In your case:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

constructor(@Inject(Injector) private readonly injector: Injector) {}

private get toastService() {
    return this.injector.get(ToastrService);
}

handleError(error: any): void {
    this.toastService.error("An unexpected error","Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the custom error handler was receiving dependencies, which themselves needed something that wasn't injected explicitly in the module.

```js
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler,
      deps: [
        BugReporterService, // This needed more dependencies
        NgZone,
        NgxUiDialogService,
        MessageService,
        TranslateService,
      ],
    },
```

What's counterintuitive is that it doesn't tell you which dependency is missing, so my suggestion is to divide-et-impera by commenting out dependencies until you find the culprit. Recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after i upgraded angular to 15 .. was getting this error only while running ng test so i cleared this issue by removing browser animation module in spec file from imports and I have added shared module at the top.. always check the order of your imports ..first shared module and then browser module should be in app module..and add browser animation module at the last of your core module imports..